# Does the Earth's magnetic field reversal and the corresponding magnetostrictive stress and strain make any contribution to the Earth's oblateness?

Tags: geophysics, geomagnetism

If the changing magnetic field in a power grid's transformer can induce stress and strain on the transformer core, then can the changing magnetic field of the Earth, similarly, place stresses and strains on the body of the Earth?

If it can, is it possible to estimate the size of these stresses and strains; and therefore discount the possibility that when the field collapses (during a reversal) that the oblateness of the Earth doesn't alter to such an extent that it becomes thinner at the equator than the poles and hence unstable?

Comment: Is this relevant to modelling neutron stars' oblateness?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, magnetostrictive materials are unusual. I doubt there are enough to be noticeable.

Also, Earth's magnetic field is weak, and shape changes even in strong fields are generally small.

Even so, it might not make any difference. Magnetic fields change over long times. Rocks flow over long times, especially deep underground where temperatures are high. So if rocks did change shape and raise a portion of the earth, it would flow back to normal. But that may not really be right if the time scale for rock flow is longer than magnetic field change times.